# Module position get disturbed after i download new template but keep the old one as default

Tags: module, templates

Here are the steps I followed -

1. Downloaded new template
2. Automatically the new template became the default one
3. I reverted back to old template

Result - Module position (main menu) get changed.

I am unable to understand the reason why this is happening....

**New Issue :** 
I tried to make a copy of my joomla site to another folder and decided to work with new template in the new folder . So there are two folders - one original and another copy. Now I started working with copy folder,and change the default template as new one and updated module positions accordingly...but when I opened the joomla site with the old version , all the changes that I made in new folder is here! I went to back-end for the older version and see that the new template is default set for old site also..why this is happening. As I expect it to be set with the old template and the new folder only with new template. 
Please help, I know I must be making some blunder here but unable to understand. Is this because both are pointing to same DB?
Old template - Breeze3
New template - Corsa 
This is just done for learning purpose. But stuck with the situation that I am not able to maintain separate copy of same site with different template.

Comment: What template did you install, and what template did you use originally?

Comment: Oh, I really do hope the developer hasn't used the script.php to automatically set it as active, along with other actions :/

Comment: @Lodder You mean like automatically change the module positions in the default template to the corresponding positions in his template? That would be fun...

Comment: @VilleNiemi - I do not agree with this happening at all. What if the user accidentally installs the wrong template for example? There are a few things that could happen. All of which would result in the user having to revert back to the previous template, and then assign all their modules back to their previous positions. I don't know any major template providers that do this, and most likely never would

Comment: @Lodder, I just tested the JSN Corsa template, and it actually *does* set itself as default upon installation, no questions asked. The installation script is close to 700 lines long, not sure what else it does...

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding your initial question:**

I just installed the free version of the [JSN Corsa template](http://www.joomlashine.com/joomla-templates/jsn-corsa-joomla-template-details.html) on a test site, and as you say, the template is automatically set as default after installation. **This is not good practice in my opinion.**

I could not replicate the problem with the main menu getting changed, but if you also used the <kbd>Install sample data</kbd> button, all your original settings will be overwritten, including your menu settings.

[image: Install sample data]

**Regarding the new issue**
As you discovered yourself, if you duplicate the files from your Joomla installation, both folders will use the same database, and any change you make in one instance of Joomla will also affect the other. More substantial changes (like installing extensions) will probably give you error messages when files and database information don't match.

The solution is to duplicate your files *and* your database, thus creating two completely separate Joomla installations.

Answer (score 0):

Check the position of the menu for New template whether it is correctly named or the position you are using for new template is given the new template one or the old template.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this issue by creating new database for the copy of my joomla site. And then changing configuration.php to point out the new database. And now I see changes separate for both the folders.

Answer (score 0):

Have you **changed the LOGS and TMP path according to the folders**. I guess that's the issue. Change the path from admin and then check. I don't think you will find the issues that both of them are working same.

**Also try creating different Database** for both the folders, as the CMS completely works and depends on the database. *So any change on one site would reflect other as well.*